# A program in C++ to Determine day of the week of any year using the fact that october 4,2020 was Sunday

Tags: c++, date

I have to write a program in C++ which uses the fact that October 4,2020 was Sunday and determines the day on any given date between 1/1/1900 and 31/12/2500.
I don't know from where to get started.
What approach should I use ?
I can't use any external library, OOP , structs or enums.
I just want to know the logic.

Comment: How much C++ experience do you have? You can create an `enum` for week, and a `struct` for month, with the week returning the day of the week given a number 1-7/0-6, and the month having x number and days and maybe a starting day of the week. Then, make a function that runs through months moving backwards, creating a month struct (and storing it in an array `calendar`). You gotta also add years using the same approach, and watch out for leap-years and non-leap years (every 3/4 100 years..)

Comment: By the way, community guidelines on Stack Overflow say you should not post imprecise questions like yours. Rather, do the work yourself and return specific bugs or problems. It's also a much better coding mentality than asking for help when you can't figure something out - really put in the work first or you won't learn. So watch out the next times you post, make it useful to anyone looking at the site.
Best of luck though!

Comment: Keep in mind: Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial years are leap years if they are exactly divisible by 400.

Comment: Notice that http://musl.libc.org/ is open source and has such a function (in C). See e.g. [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). You might adapt the existing C code to C++. See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and look for inspiration also inside the C code of [the GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). You might also study the source code of [Qt](https://qt.io/) or of [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: @MaximeFranchot I am just starting out with C++. I have to solve this without using struct or enums. I asked after spending some time trying to build logic. The problem I can't use any external library. Still, I am sorry for imprecise information as it was my first post on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

The approach you take here can be pretty straightforward, and only involves a bit of maths (modulo operations).

Consider your starting date as day 0. Get that date in number of days.
[Here's a tutorial on date and time in C++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm) (to get your date input as a number of days)

Get the number of days difference between the date you input and your day 0:
`dateDiff = inputDateInDays - day0` (keep the sign of that number)

Now consider `day0 mod 7` as Sunday. Assume `day0 mod 7 = 0` so that
`dateDiff mod 7 = dayOfTheWeek`, with 1 being Monday, 2 being Tuesday, until 6 being Satursday. That's it.

TL;DR (pseudo-code):

```
day0 = // Your original date in number of days
dateInput = // Your input date
dayInput = // Convert dateInput into number of days
dateDiff = dayInput - dayInput

// 0 <= dateDiff % 7 <= 6. So figure which number corresponds to which day.
return dateDiff % 7
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to do it without using structs or enums. Just by keeping 4th October,2020 as a relative point and then using nested if else, checking for a leap year, months with 31 days etc and calculate day accordingly

Comment: @UnikMask's answer provides you with exactly the structure you need. No struct or enum needed, just apply a day-count that goes from 0 upwards, and use the *modulo* `%` operator to filter for days, months, years, etc. using `if`/`if else` statements to decide the right number of days in months, or years.